# How to invoke an interactive bash shell as another user with initial commands?

Tags: bash, unix, ssh

I currently have a RemoteCommand, `RemoteCommand sudo su - admin-user` set up in my ssh config that allows me to connect to a system and immediately switch users to an admin user. This is because I must only make changes to the system as that admin-user, the admin-user does not have a password, and I am not allowed to add my public key to the system to connect without specifying a password. This works perfectly; I'm able to login as "login-user", and it immediately switches me to the admin-user.

However, I want to do the same, *and* create a temporary function that would allow me to run a common command in a more shorthand manner. This is because I am not allowed to change the admin-user's bashrc.

My thought in setting this up was to do the following in my ssh config:

```bash
HOST SYSTEM
    Hostname 12.34.56.78
    User login-user
    RemoteCommand sudo -Hu admin-user /usr/bin/bash --init-file <(echo ". ~/bashrc; function testy() { ls ; }") -li
    ...
```

In this case, I'm just testing with a function that runs ls. Just using a named pipe to source the normal bashrc and add a func to the new shell via an init file/rc file.

This creates an interactive bash shell as the admin-user as expected, but upon trying to run the function `testy` in this shell, I get `bash: testy: command not found`. Doing the same **without** switching users in the same step works, but not if I add the flags to run the shell as admin-user. I can't figure out how to get this working. Any help using this approach or another is greatly appreciated!

Comment: One thing about `<(...)` is that it's bash-only syntax; the shell that's already running has to be bash to use it, so if you have `/bin/sh` _starting_ bash, that won't work, because it's `sh` that's parsing that command-line argument list.

Comment: Anyhow -- have you considered, say, `sudo -Hiu admin-usr /usr/bin/env BASH_ENV=/path/to/init-file bash ...`? Yes, it _does_ mean the file needs to exist on-disk, but it doesn't need to be in the admin user's home directory; it can be anywhere that admin user can read.

Comment: BTW, better to avoid `function foo {`, which is an 80s-era ksh-ism, and `function foo() {`, which mixes ksh and POSIX syntax in a way that's incompatible with _both_ legacy ksh and POSIX -- the modern syntax is just `testy() { ls; }`;  see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Fortunately, the system I'm connecting to is already running a bash shell. I don't believe I can place my own init file on the machine - just project-specific stuff. I can check on that though. And great to know regarding the `function blah() {}` syntax! Thank you

Comment: BTW, using `sudo -i` changes how startup works in some interesting ways that are complicated enough that I generally don't keep them in my head; it should probably be possible to do without here, and add `-li` to the arguments to bash itself rather than putting `-i` on the arguments to sudo. Not sure it'll help your problem, but I _am_ sure it'll reduce the number of moving parts that someone thinking about the problem needs to consider.

Comment: (you might also add `RequestTTY yes` to your ssh_config entry if it's not already there;  if my memory is serving me correctly, having a remote command turns it off by default -- admittedly, it's possible that's true only when that command is on the ssh command line and not in the config file, so take that one with a grain of salt)

Comment: Good point with the `-i` flag. I'll change the post, as I tested and adding `-li` to the invocation of bash does behave the same as it is currently behaving. I do have `RequestTTY yes` for this host in my ssh config as well as a `RemoteForward`, but didn't think either were pertinent.

Comment: Did you consider avoiding `sudo su - admin-user` and using `sudo admin-user command ...` only when necessary? This might reduce the risk of making mistakes with elevated privileges.

Comment: @Bodo I asked why we don't just use `sudo` for the reason you mentioned and the fact that its use is logged. I'm aware that `su` in this case is against every unix sysadmin handbook's rules. I think I was just told to switch to admin-user anyway while they create an account for me, but that hasn't happened yet.

Comment: Though since I'd be using sudo when I have that account, i may as well start getting in the habit of using it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely a named pipe sharing issue. You can use another wrapper shell:

```
HOST SYSTEM
    Hostname 12.34.56.78
    User login-user
    RemoteCommand sudo -Hiu admin-user /usr/bin/bash -c 'exec /usr/bin/bash --init-file <(echo ". ~/bashrc; function testy() { ls ; }")'
    ...
```

`. ~/.bashrc` also likely can be unnecessary but that's besides the main point.

Comment: Good call. It's been a while since I've tried to use a process substitution from the other side of a privilege boundary and completely forgot about this problem.

Comment: Beautiful, that was absolutely the issue. I understand how doing it this way eliminates the issue, but do you think you could point me in the direction of a document/article further explaining why sharing a named pipe may not work?

Comment: @PatrickGeery I have little knowledge on that as well but looking at permissions of a generated named pipe can be hint: `ls -l <(:)`. Its permissions are limited to the owner.